# Django admin model query url string on NOT EQUALS

Tags: python, django, url, django-views, django-admin

I have a simple Django ForeignKey relationship between two models in postgreSQL. The logic here is the Sample object can optionally have a foreign key into a type of sample control.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import CICharField
from django.db import models

class Sample(models.Model):
    controls_applied = models.ForeignKey(SampleControl, null=True,
                                         blank=True,
                                         on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class SampleControl(models.Model):
   id = CICharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
```

On the admin changelist for Sample, I am trying to create filter that queries all or none of Samples that have a specific control (in this case, we'll use a SampleControl with id='runcontrol'). I'm trying to craft the specific URI string to append to my changelist url as I have other filters I'm trying to run in conjunction.

To get all samples with `controls_applied= 'runcontrol'`, I can simply append the following string to my URL (notice the reference to the id of the foreign key):

```
?controls_applied__id=runcontrol
```

But if I want to get all samples that are not run control, it's more complicated. Wasn't sure what to do, so I decided to use 'startswith', which has a convenient 'notstartswith' companion that will do the inverse. When I use this, I see that the following works:

```
?controls_applied__id__startswith=runcontrol
```

However, the inverse

```
?controls_applied__id__notstartswith=runcontrol
```

gives me an error: `Unsupported lookup 'notstartswith' for CICharField or join on the field not permitted, perhaps you meant startswith or istartswith?`

Which leads to me the simple question: is there a way to specify NOT EQUALS in the query string of the URL on Django's admin site? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think admin URLs are capable of representing an `exclude` queryset filter, unless you create your own `SimpleListFilter`.

Try this in your admin.py:

```py
class WithoutControlListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = ('Without Control')
    parameter_name = 'without_control'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('runcontrol', ('Run Control')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return queryset.exclude(controls_applied=self.value())


class SampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (WithoutControlListFilter,)
```

There is a bit of info about admin filters in the [Django ModelAdmin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter).

Comment: So the only problem with this method I'm having is in my list_filters field, I'm using the "a tuple, where the first element is a field name and the second element is a class inheriting from django.contrib.admin.FieldListFilter" method for all my other filters. Is there a way to use these custom SimpleListFilters in this tuple form?

Comment: @HugoKitano You would need to create your own which inherits from `FieldListFilter`. It would be much more flexible, but I've had a look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/filters.py#L162) and they are also more complicated.